# ImageMagick SVG to PNG scrambled output

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to convert a SVG file into a PNG or JPG to show it in a `<div>` in a browser, which loads it dinamically upon a press of a button.
The SVG is not malformed, as it displays it correctly on the browser. 
I use:

```
ob_start();
require("svgoutput.php");
$svg = ob_get_clean();

$image = new Imagick();
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg;
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

If I retrieve the `$svg` variable, it begins and ends every and all SVG tags correctly.

But instead of returning me an image, it returns me:

[image: fbf26c2c7089474d836985b87d5da84d[1].png]

Also, even *if* it's content displayed as text, it's too small, there's too little content.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: If I force png output (encoding in base64 and outputting it as a `img` tag), it returns me this:

http://prntscr.com/dtc9it

Comment: What you are seeing there looks like a JPEG file header printed out as text.  Is there a JPEG image in your SVG file?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau No, there are only SVG tags, such as polylines and stuff...

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Now I added a PNG to my question.

Comment: Why can I see `<div>` tags in your output?  Please attach the PNG file that's output, not a screenshot of your browser dev tools window.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau There's no PNG generated. It appears in the browser in this way too...

Comment: There's not enough information here to work out what you are doing wrong. I think you need to post more info on what you are doing (eg an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help//mcve)).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks for your effort. Meanwhile I solved the problem and answered my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I was already calling `header` in another part of the document, so that wouldn't work anymore, so I decided to encode it as base64 and put it in a `img` tag, like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $base64; ?>" alt="" />
```

The outputted image was blank, because there was a `<br>` tag at the end of the svg, which I have forgotten to remove. Now it works.

Here is the complete code *(Verified)*:

```
<?php 

ob_start();
require("index2.php");
$svg = ob_get_clean();

$image = new Imagick();
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg; 
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$image = $image->getImageBlob();
$base64 = base64_encode($image);
?>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $base64; ?>" alt="" />
```